# Django pass checkbox state to view.py when clicked

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

Hello I'm trying to pass a change in a checkbox when this box is clicked. I'm trying to accomplish this by using Ajax, but for some reason I'm unable to accomplish this. When the checkbox is clicked I'm able to see that it's clicked in my logs.

HTML/JAVASCRIPT/AJAX:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      {{ map|safe }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <form method="POST" id="form_legend">
        <h3><span style="color: #e8c4b4;">Places</span></h3>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_legend" name="cities">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="check_legend">Cities</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_legend" name="poi">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="check_legend">Points of Interest</label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function(){
      var names = [];
      $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            names.push($(this).val());
        });
      $.ajax({ url: '/api/post_form/',
                          type: "POST",
                          dataType: "json",
                          data: {names: names},
                          cache: false
                 }).done(function(data) {
                      if (data.result === true){
                          alert(data.message);
                     }
                 });
            });
  </script>
```

url.py:

```
path('api/post_form/', post_form_api, name="post_form_api"),
```

Part in view.py that captures the ajax response:

```
@csrf_exempt
def post_form_api(request):
      data = {}
      if request.method == "POST" and request.POST.get('names', None) is not None:
          form_field1 = request.POST.get('names')
          # save the form data and indicate success
          data['result'] = True
          data['message'] = "Form saved successfully"
      if request.is_ajax():
          return JsonResponse(data)
      else:
          return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Another part in view.py where I try to read and print the checkbox states:

```
def test_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST.get('names'))
```

So when I first open the webpage I get a `None` as a return from this print statement. When i click the checkbox i get in my console; `[30/Jul/2021 01:32:23] "POST /api/post_form/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2`. So i think the problem should lie somewhere in my javascript function?

Comment: when and at where you request the `test_view`?

Comment: Its another function in view.py. the full test_view is quite big so I thought to only show the relevant part. test.view eventually opens the HTML page I posted.